# What kind of file types does PHP getimagesize() return?

Tags: php, getimagesize

Does anyone know all the possible results for the 3rd value returned from PHP's getimagesize() function? Example this code below will return:

- `$imageinfo['2'] = 2;` for a `jpg` image,
- `$imageinfo['2'] = 3;` for a `png` image,
- `$imageinfo['2'] = 0;` for a `gif` image.

The numbers might not be correct above but you get the idea.

I can't find on php.net or anywhere else a list of all possible results for the 3rd value.

```
$imageinfo = getimagesize($imageurl);
$image_type  = $imageinfo['2'];
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Execute this:

```
print_r(get_defined_constants());
```

And then look for constants prefixed with IMAGETYPE_. On my PHP 5.3 installation I got these values:

```
[IMAGETYPE_GIF] => 1
[IMAGETYPE_JPEG] => 2
[IMAGETYPE_PNG] => 3
[IMAGETYPE_SWF] => 4
[IMAGETYPE_PSD] => 5
[IMAGETYPE_BMP] => 6
[IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II] => 7
[IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM] => 8
[IMAGETYPE_JPC] => 9
[IMAGETYPE_JP2] => 10
[IMAGETYPE_JPX] => 11
[IMAGETYPE_JB2] => 12
[IMAGETYPE_SWC] => 13
[IMAGETYPE_IFF] => 14
[IMAGETYPE_WBMP] => 15
[IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000] => 9
[IMAGETYPE_XBM] => 16
[IMAGETYPE_ICO] => 17
[IMAGETYPE_UNKNOWN] => 0
[IMAGETYPE_COUNT] => 18
```

As you can see Flash SWF are considered images, and actually `getimagesize()` is able to read the width and height of a SWF object. To me it seemed like a curiosity when I first discovered it, that's why mentioned it here.

Comment: Good answer, I have added another answer which includes a piece of code that will do the filtering of image file types for you.

Answer (score 6):

That index contains the value of one of PHP's [IMAGETYPE_XXX constants](https://www.php.net/image.constants). An entire list of them can be found on that page, towards the bottom. That page doesn't provide the actual INT value of each one but you should be able to print a few to get the values as necessary. You could also do a comparison check if you're looking for a specific one:

```
if ($imageinfo[2] == IMAGETYPE_IFF) {
  // Code here
}
```

Comment: BEWARE that the quoted PHP manual page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php)  starts with constatns called `IMAGE_JPG`, `IMAGE_GIF`. These are NOT the right constants. You want constants which are further down the page and start with `IMAGETYPE_GIF`, `IMAGETYPE_PNG` and so on... took me an hour to find the error.

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned constants which start with IMAGETYPE in get_defined_constants() list supported image types.

However, if you Just run this and it will tell you which ones are supported:

```
function imageTypes () {

    $imageTypes = array();

    foreach(get_defined_constants() as $key => $value){
        $keyStart = explode('_', $key);
        if($keyStart[0] == 'IMAGETYPE'){
             array_push($imageTypes, $key);
        }
    }
    return $imageTypes;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(imageTypes());
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the manual](http://php.net/getimagesize) :

> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX
>   constants indicating the type of the
>   image.

And you can find those constants onh [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php), amongst the other defined by GD

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *convert* value returned by `getimagesize()` as index `2` into something more human-readable, you may consider using a function like this one:

```
$imageTypeArray = array
(
    0=>'UNKNOWN',
    1=>'GIF',
    2=>'JPEG',
    3=>'PNG',
    4=>'SWF',
    5=>'PSD',
    6=>'BMP',
    7=>'TIFF_II',
    8=>'TIFF_MM',
    9=>'JPC',
    10=>'JP2',
    11=>'JPX',
    12=>'JB2',
    13=>'SWC',
    14=>'IFF',
    15=>'WBMP',
    16=>'XBM',
    17=>'ICO',
    18=>'COUNT'  
);

$size = getimagesize($filename);

$size[2] = $imageTypeArray[$size[2]];
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

[`getimagesize`](http://docs.php.net/getimagesize) returns a value of one of the following [`IMAGETYPE_*` constants](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php).

Answer (score 1):

The above referred pages on the image constants only give the image constant *names*, not the *integers* stored in the image constants. The scripts above do give the integers, but I found a listing of the integers on an official PHP manual page at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that in some cases on failure `getimagesize` returns `false` It happens for example for `svn` object which you may not expect.

Comment: you should post this as a comment

Comment: Did not have sufficient level to post comments... Wanted to do so.