# list() function returning strange filetype when the file size is big

Tags: php, list

I'm dealing with uploading images and I have the following php

```
list ($oldwidth, $oldheight, $type) = getimagesize($newImageLocation);
```

to get the info from the file which has just been uploaded.

If I upload a file which is eg 37kb, then the contents of $type would be IMAGETYPE_JPEG

But if I upload a larger file, say 2.5mb, then the contents of $type is 2

I'm pretty sure all my filesize allowances are all ok and I'm struggling to figure out a reason for this to happen. Anyone want to enlighten me please :)

Thanks

Comment: What `var_dump(image_type_to_mime_type($type));` returns?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282351/what-kind-of-file-types-does-php-getimagesize-return), `IMAGETYPE_JPEG` *is* `2`.

Comment: nothing it would seem...

Comment: Ah... ok. Then something else must be up. It always seems to be large files which upload and save properly, but when I'm trying to resize them it doesn't seem to be working. I've pastebin'd the bit in my function which seems to be causing problems. The first if you see doing the save function works ok. The original version of the file saves ok. After that something isn't working. Can anyone spot anything wrong? http://pastebin.com/V1sbeCjW

Comment: @Spud Machinegun: could you ask a proper question then?

Comment: Ok... I've figured out that on my localhost I can upload files up to 2mb, on the live server only 1mb, so it must be something to do with the server. But I've checked the php.ini for my localhost and the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are both at 128M

Comment: @zerkms - sorry you're post wasn't visable when I was writing mine. Sorry about the lack of clarity, forget the pastebin, can you take a look at the above comment plz

Comment: Ask a proper question - put an explanation there